# Argparsing Mutually Exclusive but Optional Choices for a Single Flag

Tags: python, argparse

### Task

I need a flag `-y` that can take in one value from `[a,b,c]` and/or one value from `[e,f,g]`, and not accept any other values. I want `[a,b,c]` to be mutually exclusive, and `[e,f,g]` to be mutually exclusive. I also require (when present) for `[a,b,c]` to come before `[e,f,g]`.

Valid Examples:

- -ya
- -yb
- -ye
- -yf
- -yaf
- -ybe
- -ybf

Invalid Examples:

- -y
- -yab
- -yea
- -yaa

### My findings

- `-type=str` lets me append the values to the end of `-y`.
- `-choices=` lets me specify valid arguments, but needs to be exhaustive. I know I can use `itertools` to generate this, but I would like the help to look like `-y[abc][efg]     Help message.`.

I'm thinking about checking after parsing whether the arguments are valid with this regex.
`-y[abc]?[efg]?[\r\n\s]?`

Is there a better way to handle this? I don't know if argparse has a built-in way to give a list of mutually exclusive arguments.

e.g. `add_argument("-y",choices=\[\[a,b,c\],\[e,f,g\]\])`

Comment: This isn't a `mutually_exclusive_group` case.  It looks more like an elaboration on `choices`.  You could put the tests in a custom `type` function, but checking values after parsing would be just as good.  `argparse` doesn't have anything to make this kind of testing easier.

Comment: `choices` just uses a simple `in` test - so they can be a flat list, or the keys of a dict, etc.  But not fancy logic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to create all the valid combinations. Something like:

```
import argparse
from itertools import product

g1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
g2 = ['e', 'f', 'g']
cross = [''.join(x) for x in product(g1, g2)]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-y', choices=g1 + g2 + cross, metavar='[abc][efg]')
args = parser.parse_args()
```